# Combining label expressions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

How to combine below expressions

```
Function FindLabel ( [Medium], [LocationStatus], [Status] )
  if  isnull (  [Medium] ) then
    FindLabel= ""
  else
    FindLabel = [Medium] & " Flowline"
  end if
End Function

Function FindLabel ( [Medium], [LocationStatus], [Status] )
  if  isnull  (  [LocationStatus] ) then
    FindLabel=""
  else
    FindLabel = "    Location-" & [LocationStatus]
  end if
End Function

Function FindLabel ( [Medium], [LocationStatus], [Status] )
  if  isnull (  [Status] ) then
    FindLabel=""
  else
    FindLabel = "    Status-" & [Status]
  end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this?  Outputs a label that has `Medium`, `LocationStatus`, and `Status` for each value that exists.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [Medium], [LocationStatus], [Status] )
    med = ""
    loc = ""
    stat = ""    

    if not isnull (  [Medium] ) then
        med = [Medium] & " Flowline"
    end if

    if not isnull  (  [LocationStatus] ) then
        loc = "    Location-" & [LocationStatus]
    end if

    if not isnull (  [Status] ) then
        stat = "    Status-" & [Status]
    end if

    FindLabel = med & " " & loc & " " & stat
End Function
```